# Developing Geoprocessing Tool in ArcPy

Tags: python, gis, arcpy

I'm trying to make what into a geoprocessing tool that can be reused in ArcMap, but I'm receiving the following error. It looks like an issue with the way that I'm formatting the where_query variable, but I can't seem to get it right.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ArcPy\mean_center_drift.py", line 19, in <module>
    arcpy.Select_analysis(in_feature, year_out_name, where_query)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 84, in Select
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression 1
Failed to execute (Select).
```

and here is the code in its current form.

```
import os
import arcpy

in_feature  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
out_features  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
origin_year = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
field_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

for x in range(10, 140, 10):
    year_range = int(origin_year) + x
    where_query = 'field_name' <= "{0}.format(year_range)"

    year_out_name = os.path.join(out_features, "Years_{0}".format(x))
    mean_out_name = os.path.join(out_features, "Mean_{0}".format(x))

    arcpy.Select_analysis(in_feature, year_out_name, where_query)

    arcpy.MeanCenter_stats(year_out_name, mean_out_name, "#", "#", "#")
```

Any help that you could provide would be much appreciated!

Comment: You may also want to post over at [Geographic Information Systems](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) - lots of arcpy folks over there.  ```where_query``` looks suspect - what are you trying to do there?

Comment: I am trying to define the input in a variable for the where clause in the Select_analysis() function. - http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000005000000

Comment: Don't [cross-post questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/157337/1872)

Answer (score 1):

`where_query` is *constructed* wrong.

```
>>> where_query = 'field_name' <= "{0}.format(year_range)"
>>> where_query
True
>>> year_range = 2010
>>> where_query = "'field_name' <= {0}".format(year_range)
>>> where_query
"'field_name' <= 2010"
>>>
```

I'm not familiar with `arcpy` if the single quotes around `field_name` are not required,  remove them.

If you are not using an editor with syntax highlighting, you should consider it.

`print` statements/functions are a quick and easy way to check suspect variables.

Answer (score 0):

[Someone in the GIS StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157337/executeerror-error-000358-using-a-variable-within-arcpy-select-analysis?noredirect=1#157340) was able to help me using the below solution.

```
import os
import arcpy

in_feature  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
out_features  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
origin_year = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
field_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

path = arcpy.Describe(in_feature).path
new_field_name = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(path, field_name)

for x in range(10, 140, 10):
    year_range = int(origin_year) + x
    where_query = """{0} <= {1}""".format(new_field_name, year_range)

    year_out_name = os.path.join(out_features, "Years_{0}".format(x))
    mean_out_name = os.path.join(out_features, "Mean_{0}".format(x))

    arcpy.Select_analysis(in_feature, year_out_name, where_query)

    arcpy.MeanCenter_stats(year_out_name, mean_out_name, "#", "#", "#")
```